# Jquery Droppable Draggable Not Working in Chrome/Safari and IE 9

Tags: jquery, webkit, draggable

The following Jquery Drag/Drop does not work in:

Internet Explorer: 9
Safari: 5+
Chrome: 19+

In Chrome and Safari, the drop is not working.
When I drop the draggable, it reverts back as it should, but then it reappears on the cursor. I must CLICK the droppable for the hit to register.

In IE 9, the drag is not working. It does not move.

What I need it to do is to have an inventory on the right. This inventory will be a slider (which I have removed for the sake of simplicity). When you drag an item from the inventory, it reverts back and then I place that image source on to the drop's image placeholder.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.circles').draggable({//The drag does not fire in IE9
        revert: "invalid",
        helper: "clone"

    });

    $('.circleTargetContainer').droppable({
        accept: '.circles',
        activeClass: 'ui-state-active',
         drop: function( event, ui ) {

             alert("HIT");//the hit does not register in Chrome and IE
                var popImage = $(ui.draggable).find('img').attr("src");
                //set placeholder to popImage
                var childImage = $(this).find('img');
                $(childImage).attr('src', popImage);


            }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When playing around with IE9, is always good to check your compatibility issues, and try out on different ones.

[image]

and you will find out that in IE9 Compatibility View, it works normally, so all you need is to [force IE to load this view](http://webdesign.about.com/od/internetexplorer/qt/force-compatibility-view-in-ie.htm) instead the default one.

In regarding Chrome 19, I have no problem, unless it's not this what it is suppose to do

1. I click in one element in the right side
2. I drag it to the drop zone
3. I stop clicking
4. Chosen element sticks in the drop zone

[Screen cast can be find here](http://bit.ly/KrTuNO) showing this.

Comment: Hi, thanks. In Chrome and Safari, the problem is #4 in your list for me. It does not stick to the drop zone. Instead, it sticks to my cursor.

Comment: OK, it seems that for Chrome and Safari it matters WHERE you click. If I click on the image. If I grab a hold of the IMG inside the div, I get a "don't sign" (the circle with a slash through it). If I grab the div without touching the img, I can drag it fine. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Maybe you should use image as a background of a `div` and then in the `drop()` parse `var popImage = $(ui.draggable).css("background-image");`?

Comment: Hello,yes changing it from an image inside a div to a background image did the trick along with setting the compatibility mode of IE 9. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your demo on Safari 5.1.7 and Chrome 19 and it works well. Only in IE it doesn't work at all.
[Checking validity of the html returned 2 errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3a%2f%2fproductionworksinc.com%2fdnd%2fdnd.html), just try to add `alt` element to the images and check if it works with it. Without this errors it should work like in the *Compatibility mode* (where it works).

Comment: See my comment for balexandre. Webkit seems to be picky about which element you click on to start the drag. Any fix for this?